# Paypal Standard Payments pay Multiple Sellers

Tags: paypal

I am changing an existing paypal standard payments button, and would like to send money directly to 2 different people (seller, and website owner). Firstly, is this possible without diving into the API, and secondly, how do I go about doing it? I have had a read of quite a bit on the PayPal site, but have had no success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through a PayPal Payments Standard button, it's not possible to pay more than one person at a time.  To pay two separate parties, you'd need to either:

- Create two separate buttons
- Use Express Checkout (which can process the payment to both parties in parallel)
- Use Adaptive Payments (which can process the payment to both parties in parallel, or in a chained fashion)